# react-datetime-picker setting date to 24 hour format

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using the react-datetime-picker. Currently it only shows the date in 12 hour format. I need to to show in 24hour format.

I have looked at a few solutions but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help??

This is how my component looks:

```
           <DateTimePicker
                clearIcon={null}
                format="y-MM-dd HH:mm"
                onChange={handleStartDateChanges}
                disableClock
                disableCalendar
                className=" text-black"
                value={values?.startDate}
                locale="en_GB"
                timeFormat="HH:mm"
                is24Hour
              />
```

I have imported it from this package:

```
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Locale with React DateTime, you will need to import one.

You can use the Locale from moment by simply using this import:

```
import 'moment/locale/en-gb'
```